# Having Trouble Enabling pg_stat_statements to Enable Heroku pg:outliers

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to run the pg:outliers command in the Heroku command line tools and I am getting the following error:

```
 ▸    pg_stat_statements extension need to be installed in the public schema first.
 ▸    You can install it by running:
 ▸    
 ▸    CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
```

I ran "CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements; in my Postgres database and verified that it is there with `psql -d database_name -c '\dx'` which shows:

```
                                            List of installed extensions
        Name        | Version |   Schema   |                              Description                               
--------------------+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
 pg_stat_statements | 1.8     | public     | track planning and execution statistics of all SQL statements executed
 plpgsql            | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)
```

But when I run `heroku pg:outliers` I still get the above error saying I don't have the extension installed in the public schema.

I must be misunderstanding the instructions to install it but I can't find anything clarifying the process that would indicate what I am doing wrong.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong to get this extension to run properly? Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a fix, but have you tried adding pg_stat_statements using the heroku command: `heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL -a example-app`

More details can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search#pg_stat_statements